# dbus systemctl error : GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name com.example.Interface was not provided by any .service files

Tags: qml

I am new to systemctl.
I want to register a binary file using dbus with systemctl and use it.

When the binary file created by cmake is executed, it works normally.

However, if you run systemctl after registering the service file, it does not work properly.

There are server, clientA, and B services to register systemctl.
Here is the service file.

```
[Unit]
Description=Server Service...
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/test/bin/dbusExample_Server
ExecStop=/opt/test/bin/dbusExample_Server
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=60

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

```
[Unit]
Description=Client A Service...
After=network.target

[Service]
BusName=com.example.Interface
ExecStart=/opt/test/bin/helloString
ExecStop=/opt/test/bin/helloString
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=60
Environment="DISPLAY=:0"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

```
[Unit]
Description=Client B Service...
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/test/bin/B/dbusExample_Client_B
ExecStop=/opt/test/bin/B/dbusExample_Client_B
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=60
Environment="DISPLAY=:0"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I run.

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start server.service
sudo systemctl start clientA.service
sudo systemctl start clientB.service
```

In my program, when qml is executed on client A and a message is input, a message is sent from the server, and a message is also received from client B.

Enter a message and check it.

```
sudo systemctl status server.service
sudo systemctl status clientA.service
sudo systemctl status clientB.service
```

When I checked the status of clientA.service, I could see the following error.

```
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name com.example.Interface was not provided by any .service files
```

The path to my .service file is as follows.

```
/lib/systemd/system
```

I checked that it should be in a different path through a search, and moved the following path

```
/.local/share/dbus-1/services
/etc/systemd/system
```

But I haven't been able to verify that it works.

What points do I need to fix for it to work properly? Any help would be greatly appreciated!